# System.AccessViolationException in Entity Framework Core Add-Migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I get a "System.AccessViolationException" when trying to create a migration with Entity Framework Core.

I already tested inside Visual Studio Package Manager Console and from PowerShell using CLI, both result in the same error.

Here is the CLI example and the result:

```
PS dotnet ef migrations add [migration-name] --project [project-name] --startup-project [project-name]
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.GetStackFramesInternal(System.Diagnostics.StackFrameHelper, Int32, Boolean, System.Exception)
> at System.Diagnostics.StackFrameHelper.InitializeSourceInfo(Int32, Boolean, System.Exception)
> at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.CaptureStackTrace(Int32, Boolean, System.Exception)
> at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace..ctor(System.Exception, Boolean)
> at System.Exception.get_StackTrace()
> at System.Exception.ToString()
> at System.Exception.ToString()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor+OperationBase.Execute(System.Action)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor+OperationBase.Execute[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor+AddMigration..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IOperationResultHandler, System.Collections.IDictionary)
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean, Boolean)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Object[])
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, System.Object[])
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor.Execute(System.String, System.Object, System.Collections.IDictionary)
> at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid4[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon, System.__Canon)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.InvokeOperationImpl(System.String, System.Collections.IDictionary)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.InvokeOperation[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.String, System.Collections.IDictionary)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.OperationExecutorBase.AddMigration(System.String, System.String, System.String)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
> at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(System.String[])
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(System.String[])

I've also tried things like restarting the PC and Windows Memory Diagnostic tests, but nothing.

Guess it's important to say that I was successfully creating migrations a couple days ago, but this specifically migration is not working. And also the migration is quite simple: just a new property on a class (new column on a table).

Do anyone got any clue about what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a teammate to get my branch and try to add the migration. It showed another error. It was just a field that should be a property.

The problem was that the "real" exception was being overrided by the `AccessViolationException`. As I can see, something in my environment/pc is making exception rethows to make an `AccessViolationException` instead. Don't know why.
It already happened in other 2 exceptions that I got testing/running my system, but on those cases I was able to debug and find the first exception and solve it. On this case (EF Core, Add-Migration), I couldn't debug.

Well, I know that this answer don't solve the `AccessViolationException`, but at least shows what I've experienced, so I guess it was better to share and choose it as an answer.

If someone knows why the `AccessViolationException` is being throw instead of the original exception, then I'd be pleased to accept the answer.